# echo statement for false php function

Tags: php, function, return

I have created a function as follows:

```
//function for first name field
    function name ($fname) {

        //validate to see if field is empty
        if (empty($fname)) {
            return (false);
        } 

        $welcome_string = '<p> Welcome ' . $fname . '. We\'re glad you\'re here! Take a look around!</p>';
        return $welcome_string;

    }//end fname function
```

When the function passes the check I echo the function and get the welcome_string. However, I need to display an error outside of the function when it returns false.  I cannot figure out how to do this.  Below is the code where I call the function:

```
echo name($fname);
```

Comment: `if (!name($fname)){echo 'error';}else{echo $fname;}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is add a check for that:

```
$result = name($fname);

if ($result) {
    echo $result;
} else {
    echo "There was an error.";
}
```

Using a ternary if, you can do this in shorthand:

```
$result = name($fname);
echo $result ? $result : "There was an error.";
```

Or even shorter without introducing a new variable:

```
echo name($fname) ?: "There was an error.";
```

Comment: Do I add this inside my current function?

Comment: No, at the place where you now have `echo name($fname);`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
$result = name($fname); 
echo $result?$result:"error message";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function greeting($name)
{
    if (empty($name))
        return false;
    $welcome_string = 'Welcome ' . $name . ". We're glad you're here! Take a look around!\n";

    return $welcome_string;
}

foreach(['Rita', 'Sue', '', null, 0, '0'] as $name)
    echo ($message = greeting($name))
        ? $message
        : "Who are you?\n";
```

Output:

```
Welcome Rita. We're glad you're here! Take a look around!
Welcome Sue. We're glad you're here! Take a look around!
Who are you?
Who are you?
Who are you?
Who are you?
```